# Are all forces given by a field conservative forces?

Tags: forces, field-theory, dissipation, conservative-field

When teaching us electromagnetism, our professor first introduced us to the concept of "field". Several lessons later, he proved that electric field force is a conservative force.

But I think the assert that there is something called "electric **field**" implies that electric field force is conservative to some extend, because  according to Wikipedia, "a field is a physical quantity that has a value for each point in space and time" by definition, that is, the force given by a field should be a function of space and time, regardless of velocity or anything else.

Am I right? At least, I can't come up with a [non-conservative force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force) given by a field.

Comment: The magnetic field is not conservative.

Comment: @ACuriousMind We haven't learnt that yet...If the magnetic field is not conservative, I'll be wrong and our textbook will be reasonable :)

Comment: Electric fields don't have to be conservative, either. If they were, your electronic devices wouldn't work at all, since there would be no transformers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not every force field you can imagine is conservative.
A force field is conservative if its line integral is path-independent, that is to say,

$$\int_C \vec F \cdot d \vec x = U(a)-U(b)$$

For every curve C with end points $a,b$. $U$ is some scalar function.

If the force field is the gradient of a scalar field, this is automatically verified:

$$\int_C \vec F \cdot d \vec x =\int_C \vec \nabla U \cdot d \vec x = \int_C d U = U(a)-U(b) $$

So if there exist a potential energy field $U$ from which our force field $\vec F$ is generated ($ \vec F = \vec \nabla U$), the force field $\vec F$ will be conservative.

An example of vector field which is not conservative is the 2-dimensional field $\vec v = (y^3, x)$. Let's say you want to go from the point (1,0) to the point (2,1). You can go there directly along a straight line, or pass through the point (2,0) and then go towards the point (2,1), always moving along straight lines. You will find that the integral

$$ \int_{(1,0)}^{(2,1)} (y^3,x) \cdot (dx, dy) $$

Is equal to 7/4 in the first case and to 2 in the second case. So the integral is path-dependent, and the field is not conservative.

This example is taken from these notes: http://www-astro.physics.ox.ac.uk/~sr/lectures/multiples/Lecture3reallynew.pdf